# map from equaliser/kernel is a monomorphism

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

I'm going through lecture notes on categories and homological algebra. There seems to be a very basic fact that's eluding me.

Let $C$ be a category and $f,g\in Hom(X_0,X_1)$, such that $K=\ker(f,g)$ exists, then one gets a map $i:K\to X_0$. This map is a monomorphism. The proof of that fact goes as follows :

Take a pair of parallel arrows $h,k: Y \rightrightarrows K$ such that $ih=ik=w$ then $fw=fih=gih=gik=gw$. **Hence $w$ factors uniquely through $i$**, thus $h=k$.

I get that $w$ factoring uniquely through $i$ implies that $h=k$, I don't get why that string of equality implies $w$ does indeed factor uniquely through $i$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not too deep into category theory. What is $Y$ and what are parallel arrows? Maybe you want to try a contradiction? Suppose $w$ does not factor uniquely through $i$. Can you find $fw\ne gw$?

Comment: @user408858 $Y$ is an object in $C$, parallel arrows are morphisms with common domain and codomain i.e. $f,g \in Hom(X_0,X_1)$ are parallel arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, that the kernel is a special limit, namely that of the diagram $f,g\colon X_0\rightrightarrows X_1$. According to the universal property of the limit, any morphism $w\colon Y\rightarrow X_0$, that fulfills $f\circ w=g\circ w$ (therefore is a cone of the diagram), factors uniquely over their kernel (limit of the diagram) $K=\ker(f,g)$:
[image]

In your proof, the morphism $w=ih=ik\colon Y\rightarrow X_0$ fulfills the condition $f\circ w=g\circ w$ of being a cone of the diagram $f,g\colon X_0\rightrightarrows X_1$, which is exactly what the string of equalities shows.

Comment: I would be ok with this answer, but in the lecture notes this remark (that this map is a monomorphism) comes before the definition of limits and colimits, so I'm thinking there's an "obvious, low-tech" reason as to why that string of equality implies $w$ factors uniquely through $i$.

Comment: Ok actually I gave it a little bit more thought and the diagram you wrote is also just a visualisation of the isomorphism $Hom_C(Y,\ker(X_0\rightrightarrows X_1)) \simeq \ker(Hom_C(Y,X_0)\rightrightarrows Hom_C(Y,X_1))$, so the argument works without needing to involve limits. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I only mentioned the limit to give you a more general context/bigger picture. The definition of the kernel already includes the universal property of unique factorisation. (The unique being necessary to prove, that kernels are unique up to isomorphism.) You're welcome!